# Sitemesh, Cannot construct Factory : com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.DefaultFactory:

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, sitemesh

I use the version 2.4.2 of SiteMesh with Spring

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I deploy my application with the name **myApp.war** and everything works properly. I need to deploy the application **myapp##versionApp.war** name and this name gives problems.

The error is

> Cannot construct Factory : com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.DefaultFactory: com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException: Could not read config file : /WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

I have found that exists in the WEB-INF / directory / file the sitemesh.xml.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same in version 2.4

The DefaultFactory will try to use the ServletContext().getRealPath(), but eventually tries to read from contexPath. This is an error i think.

To get around this you'll have to create a Factory of your own and set it in your web.xml env

Copy the DefaultFactory for the code

```
public class MyFactory extends com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.BaseFactory {

    public MyFactory () {
        // Do stuff
        // delete every thing that sets the config path or simply set

        String configFile = null;

        // Do stuff
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Your web.xml will look like so

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

        <env-entry>
            <env-entry-name>sitemesh.factory</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>my.sitemesh.MyFactory</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in version 2.3 while upgrading Tomcat version from 7 to 9 for our legacy application.

Problem was these two lines on DefaultFactory class.

```
 this.configFileName = config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("sitemesh.configfile");
 .
 .
 .
 .

 is = this.configFile.toURL().openStream();
```

By defining configFileName on web.xml file as a context-param, filename problem can be solved.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>sitemesh.configfile</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Deprecated method usage on config file stream causes a problem. To solve this issue custom factory class should be written. You can directly copy the defaultFactory and replace this line

```
 is = this.configFile.toURL().openStream();
```

with this

```
 is = new FileInputStream(this.configFile);
```

This change will solve the input stream issue.

My adding environment entry you can add your custom class to sitemesh. This lines should be placed to web.xml file

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>sitemesh.factory</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>your.custom.factory.SitemeshFactory</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

DefaultFactory.java uses the Deprecate File.toURL() API. there is a problem reading sitemesh.xml file.

Please update your sitemesh version to [sitemesh:2.5-atlassian-11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/opensymphony/sitemesh/2.5-atlassian-11)

[sitemesh:2.5-atlassian-11 Bugfix commit](https://github.sec.samsung.net/FinancePlatform/smps_server_spt_payment/pull/23/files)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the context-param, param-value in WEB-INF works for me.
I know this is not a perfect solution, but i have tried a lot of things and nothing except this works.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>sitemesh.configfile</param-name>
    <param-value>/opt/tomcat/xxx/yyy/zzz/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml</param-value>
```

*xxx/yyy/zzz is my three level context, the war file is like this xxx#yyy#zzz#app-name.war